# Websocket connection to Rabbitmq over SSL through ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, elastic-load-balancer

I have installed a rabbitmq server on my AWS instance that is behind a load balancer. I am currently able to connect, send and receive messages using js from an http url. However when I attempt the same feat from an https url I cannot successfully maintain a connection.

The following snippet shows the several tacks I have taken so far:

```
var ws =  null; 
if (window.location.protocol.indexOf("https") >= 0){
    //1 ws =  new WebSocket('wss://myelbpublicdns.com:15674/ws');
    //2 ws =  new WebSocket('wss://myec2publicdns.com:15674/ws');
    //3 ws =  new WebSocket('wss://myurl.com:15674/ws');
} else {
    ws =  new WebSocket('ws://' + awshost + ':15674/ws');
}    
var client = Stomp.over(ws);
client.connect(username, password, on_connect, on_error, '/');
```

So the connect via ws: works perfectly fine. 
Connect of option 1 to my ELB gets an SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN stating that the cert is for myurl.com, ok makes sense

Connect of option 2 to the ec2 instance gets an SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Connect of option 3 directly to myurl.com gets a 400 bad request.

port 15674 is open on my ELB with an ssl cert attached.

All ideas on how to get my wss: connection working are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the below and confirm so that I can try to help this one.

1. Is your certificate generated with AWS ACM?
2. Have you tried new WebSocket('wss://www.myurl.com:15674/ws');

Comment: thanks for the help. Turns out that rabbit was not going to do what we wanted to do so we moved to an xmpp implementation.